# AngularJS ngTable not updated

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, ngtable

I am using `Angular` routing in my application as well as `ngTable`. One of my pages contains a `ngTable`, and a search form, where data is coming from database using **GET** method (MongoDB) every time I search, so every time I search the `ngTable` (table) should be updated, and my problem is that the Table is updated only one time, after loading the page for the first time.

The contoller used for the partial page :

```
app.controller('SearchController',function($scope,ngTableParams,$http,$filter, $sce){

$scope.searching=function(){
    var str = $scope.search.tags;
    var TagsArry = str.split(",");

    $http.get('/api/GetDoc',{params:{title:$scope.search.title,tags:$scope.search.tags}})
        .success(function(data)
        {
            if(data.notExist!=-1){
                $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                    page: 1,            // show first page
                    count: 10           // count per page

                }, {
                    total: data.length, // length of data
                    getData: function($defer, params) {
                        $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

                    }
                });
            }
          })
        .error(function(err){

        });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue. You need to reload $scope.tableParams every time a new search occurs, so every time the search button is clicked. A simple way to do this is to wrap $scope.tableParams.reload() in a function, and then call that function when your search button is clicked.

controller code:

```
$scope.doSearch = function () {
    $scope.tableParams.reload();
}
```

html code:

```
<button ng-click="doSearch()">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the similar issue. It is a problem with the ngTable directive. It updates only when data.length changes. I had finally solved this issue, simply add this line before your $http request:

```
$scope['tableParams'] = {reload:function(){},settings:function(){return {}}};
$http.get('/api/GetDoc',{params:{title:$scope.search.title,tags:$scope.search.tags}})
    .success(function(data){
          /***** Your Code *********/
 });
```

What it does is, it resets the ng-table settings then it initilize like it does for the first time.